# Date and time format conversion in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, iso8601

I have date/time format, for example:

```
"2012-06-28T08:26:57Z"
```

What kind of date/time format is that and how can it be converted into the following format, using DateTime format in C#.:

```
"8/24/2012 4:09:17 AM"
```

Comment: Please explain where you are stuck and [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string input = "2012-06-28T08:26:57Z";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(input);
string output = dt.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For the meaning of each part of your input string, take a look at this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: How can you be sure that Parse will parse it correctly? What if he gets a date like `"2012-06-07T08:26:57Z"` Will that be 6th of July or 7th of June?

Comment: At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx it says that ISO 8601 format is parsed by `DateTime.Parse`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date/time string. The numbers are the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second (in that order).

The "T" is a placeholder. It means nothing.

The "Z" is an indicator that the time is relative to GMT, rather than in a local time zone.

Comment: The `T` probably stands for "Time".

Answer (score 1):

That is Universal Sortable date format

You can use following code to convert it

```
 var dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-06-28T08:26:57Z");
 var newdt = String.Format("{0:G}", dt);  // "6/28/2012 1:56:57 PM"
```

**Update**

You can try this also

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-06-28T08:26:57Z", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var newdt = String.Format("{0:G}", dt);
```

Comment: The formatting may be very different on different cultures. You need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx this is answer to your question. Here you can see how to create different date formats. According to this resource, you may use something like this:

```
String olddate="2012-06-28T08:26:57Z";
DateTime date=Convert.ToDateTime(olddate);
String date1=date.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt");
```

Comment: @Oded Edited answer, and going to check FAQ. Thanks for critics.

Comment: Answer is not answering the question though.

Comment: It is partial. The OP is asking for _parsing_ the original string too. This has not been answered.

Comment: You seem to have not read the question at all. How does any of the answer relate to the first string? How is that to be parsed into a `DateTime` object?

Comment: @Oded the OP told that he has DateTime object, but in incorrect format. And he want to get DateTime object in correct format. As I can see, my code will do it. Sorry if I am incorrect, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: No, the OP says he has a _string_ "2012-06-28T08:26:57Z" representing a date. He wants to convert that to a different string format. There is no `DateTime` object to begin with.

Comment: @oded thank you for pointing out. I simply misunderstood question. And finally added normal answer even though it's not needed now.

Comment: The only problem left is that the format you end up with is _wrong_. The month goes before the day in the example by the OP.

Comment: @oded fixed that too. That's why maybe sharing link is more useful because you can understand how to do it. And perhaps OP should have described date format that he wants.

Comment: OP described by posting the two strings. And yes, having the link in the answer certainly makes it more valuable.

Answer (score 1):

try to use something liKe this.

```
var d = DateTime.Parse("2012-08-24T04:09:17Z");
Console.WriteLine (d.ToString("G"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that 'General date/time pattern (long time).' in .net is culture specific. From msdn:

```
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 6/15/2009 1:45 PM (en-US)
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 15/06/2009 13:45 (es-ES)
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 2009/6/15 13:45 (zh-CN)
```

Comment: The OP wants the opposite parsing.

Comment: Ou, sorry, I was confused with multiple 'this' in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the date into string like this

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss")
```

Here date is a variable in which a date is present

or try this

```
string timeString = "11/12/2009 13:30:00.000";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true); 
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", culture);
```

These links might also be helpful to you.

[DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

[String Format for DateTime [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert Universal datetime to local time

```
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-08-25T06:57:57Z","yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var newformat = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use :)

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-06-28T08:26:57Z");